# Добрый день, python скрипт присылает пустые значения "{}" на сервер

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest

Я хочу онлайн мониторить температуру своего компа с помощью датчика, температуру он измеряет, получает значение, но на сервер приходят пустые json значения, вот код:

```
import requests

import glob
import time
import json

url="https://test-simpledimple.herokuapp.com/api/getdata";
base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28-3c01f0955e8c')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()

    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')

    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        return temp_c

//вот тут что то происходит не так
while 0==0:
    payload = {"temperature": read_temp()}
    response = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload))
    time.sleep(1)


print(response)
```

Comment: ну так дебажьте код свой. выводите на печать значения, которые получаете и отправляете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было указать формат json в заголовке запроса, поэтому сервер не мог распарсить данные, считал их undercoding типом

```
    header = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
    payload = {"temperature": read_temp()}

    response = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers=header)
    time.sleep(1)
```